# String to numeric conversion using regex in scala

Tags: regex, scala

Hi have an array of numbers as string:

`val original_array = Array("-0,1234567",......)` which is a string and I want to convert to a numeric Array.

```
val new_array      = Array("1234567", ........)
```

How can I aheive this in scala?

Using original_array.toDouble is giving error

Comment: Why do you consider "-0,1234567" as 1234567, not -0.1234567 ?

Comment: Because the it is an array of monthly income as given in the data

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra, please explain further. Your array isn't a string, as you state, and its first element has two numbers in, so we need you to explain the rules for what you want as output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is ...

```
val arrNums = Array("123", "432", "99").map(_.toDouble)
```

... but this a little dangerous because it will throw if any of the strings are not proper numbers.

This is safer...

```
val arrNums = Array("123", "432", "99").collect{ case n 
    if n matches """\d+""" => n.toDouble
}
```

... but you'll want to use a regex pattern that covers all cases.  This example won't recognize floating point numbers ("1.1") or negatives ("-4").  Something like `"""-?\d*\.?\d+"""` might fit your requirements.